# Error happens on git when I push with multiple github accounts on the same computer, even after I set SSH

Tags: git, github, ssh

I made a new git local repository and I tried to do push with `git push origin master` for the first time, but I caught the error below:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '52.192.72.89' to the list of known hosts.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

According to my searching, it seems this is the common case which happens when one tries to use multiple github accounts in one computer machine, and that's exactly what I'm doing.

I've already tried the common solution of setting SSH for all the github accounts I have in my computer. I made the directory of `.ssh` and set the required files like this:

```
.ssh/
　├ config
　├ id_myGithubAccount1_rsa
　├ id_myGithubAccount1_rsa.pub
  ├ id_myGithubAccount2_rsa
　├ id_myGithubAccount2_rsa.pub　　
　└ known_hosts
```

`id_myGithubAccountX_rsa` is of course the RSA secret key of `myGithubAccountX` (X = 1,2) and `.pub` is the public key of it.

The content of `config` file is as following:

```
Host github-myGithubAccount1
  User git
  Port 22
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_myGithubAccount1_rsa
  


Host github-myGithubAccount2
  User git
  Port 22
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_myGithubAccount2_rsa
```

The content of "known_hosts" is as following:

```
github.com,13.114.40.48 ssh-rsa [Many characters] ==
52.69.186.44 ssh-rsa [many characters]==
```

After that, I tried to use git of `myGithubAccount2` with the commands below:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:<ACCOUNT_NAME>/<YOUR_REPSITORY>.git
```

and

```
$ git config --global user.name "<YOUR_NAME>"
$ git config --global user.email <YOUR_EMAIL>
```

Then, I put `ssh -T github-myGithubAccount2` and I've got the message below:

```
Hi myGithubAccount2! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Many articles in the Web say this is all and we can use git of `myGithubAccount2`. However, the result is the beginning of this question.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to use git of myGithubAccount2 with the commands below:
>
> ```
> git remote add origin git@github.com:<ACCOUNT_NAME>/<YOUR_REPSITORY>.git
> ```

That does not use `myGithubAccount2`

```
git remote set-url origin github-myGithubAccount2:<ACCOUNT_NAME>/<YOUR_REPSITORY>.git
```

That would use the right key.

It needs to use the exact `Host` entry 'github-myGithubAccount2' from the `~/.ssh/config` file.

Comment: Thank you. I tried ` git remote set-url origin myGithubAccount2 :<ACCOUNT_NAME>/<YOUR_REPOSITORY>.git `  but the  terminal returned the message below
```usage: git remote set-url [--push] <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]
   or: git remote set-url --add <name> <newurl>
   or: git remote set-url --delete <name> <url>

    --push                manipulate push URLs
    --add                 add URL
    --delete              delete URLs```

Comment: @jazzGeek Did you type the command in the root folder of your local cloned repository? Did you replace `<ACCOUNT_NAME>/<YOUR_REPOSITORY>` by the right values?

Comment: There's a bit of stray whitespace in the above, between `myGithubAccount2` and `:<ACCOUNT_NAME>/...`. Trim that away.

Comment: Yes. I typed this command at the directory where `.git` folder exists, and I replaced `<ACCOUNT_NAME>/<YOUR_REPOSITORY>` by my real account name and repository name of my github account.

Comment: @jazzGeek As torek commented, I had an extra space between the key and the rest of the URL: I have removed it in the answer

Comment: Thank you. I tried and I could change url, but it returns the error :  `ssh: Could not resolve hostname myGithubAccount2: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: @jazzGeek OK: I have edited the answer: can you try again the `set-url` command?

Comment: Succeeded. I just misspelled the exact `Host` name as you pointed. Now I saw my remote repository  accepted the push. Thank you very much.